# C++ Index may have a value of '1000000' which is out of bounds

Tags: c++, arrays, clang, clion, lint

## Intro

I do performance tests with the following array sizes 1,000,000, 10,000,000 and 100,000,000. My IDE (CLion) shows me the following warning message:

> Index may have a value of '1000000' which is out of bounds

This warning appears only in the first for-loop in each line where `bodies[i]` is accessed:

```cpp
    void doPerformanceTestBodiesAsAoS(const size_t n) {
        auto *bodies = new Body<long double, double[3], double[3]>[n];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            bodies[i].mass = static_cast<double>(i);
            bodies[i].position[0] = static_cast<double>(i);
            bodies[i].position[1] = static_cast<double>(i + 1);
            bodies[i].position[2] = static_cast<double>(i + 2);
            bodies[i].velocity[0] = static_cast<double>(i);
            bodies[i].velocity[1] = static_cast<double>(i + 1);
            bodies[i].velocity[2] = static_cast<double>(i + 2);
        }

        const auto startTimeInNanoSeconds = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < (n - 1); ++i) {
            const size_t nextBodyIndex = i + 1;
            std::sqrt(
                    PhysicsEngine::math::pow2(bodies[i].position[0] - bodies[nextBodyIndex].position[0]) +
                    PhysicsEngine::math::pow2(bodies[i].position[1] - bodies[nextBodyIndex].position[1]) +
                    PhysicsEngine::math::pow2(bodies[i].position[2] - bodies[nextBodyIndex].position[2])
            );
        }
        auto endTimeInNanoSeconds = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout.precision(17);
        std::cout << "Processing of AoS took: "
                  << static_cast<long double>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(endTimeInNanoSeconds - startTimeInNanoSeconds).count()) / 1e+9 << " seconds for N = " << n << std::endl;

        delete[] bodies;
    }
// ...

TEST(PerformanceTest, PerformanceTest1MioBodiesAsAoS) {
    doPerformanceTestBodiesAsAoS(1'000'000);
}

TEST(PerformanceTest, PerformanceTest10MioBodiesAsAoS) {
    doPerformanceTestBodiesAsAoS(10'000'000);
}

TEST(PerformanceTest, PerformanceTest100MioBodiesAsAoS) {
    doPerformanceTestBodiesAsAoS(100'000'000);
}
```

## Problem

I'm now unsure whether this warning **is a false positive (?!)** or whether I'm missing something and thus possibly falsifying my performance tests.

## What have I already done

1. I have checked that on my system sizes 1,000,000 - 100,000,000 do not exceed the MAX_INT value to ensure indexing does not arithmetically overflow. This shouldn't happen because `int` is 4 bytes and `size_t` is 8 bytes on my system.
2. I restarted my IDE several times, cleaned up caches etc.
3. I changed every `size_t` to `int` because I assume the index operator `[]` expects an `int` instead of `size_t`? But that didn't resolve the warning.
4. I searched for similar question but couldn't find any.

So I'm asking for a code review, whether it's false positive or I have a bug.

## Additional information

1. I am using Windows 10 64, MingGW and an Intel processor.
2. The `typedef` of `size_t` is:

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN64
  __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;
#else
  typedef unsigned int size_t;
#endif /* _WIN64 */
```

Comment: Have you written a test program that simply prints `sizeof(size_t)`?  Do you see `-D_WIN64` in the compiler command line?

Comment: What is 100’000'000 * sizeof (Body... ) ?

Comment: @Den-Jason Have you written a test program that simply prints sizeof(size_t)? Yes.  Do you see -D_WIN64 in the compiler command line? No.

Comment: @QuentinUK 100’000'000 * sizeof(Body<long double, double[3], double[3]>) = 6400000000

Comment: @Dawid maybe it’s using 32 bits (max 2147483647) does `Body<long int, int[3], int[3]>` give the same error?

Comment: @QuentinUK Yes, the warning still appears. PS: 100'000'000 * sizeof(Body<long int, int[3], int[3]>) = 2800000000

Comment: @Dawid can you try and encapsulate it within a `try {...} catch (std::bad_alloc e) {...}` block just to see if the warning disappears OR doing a simple `null_ptr` check for `bodies`. I have a hypothesis, but I need to test it out first, before I write it out and I only have `mingw64` accessible through an online compiler which doesn't produce warnings.

Comment: @MilanŠ The warning is still there. In addition I get the warnings that the code inside the catch block and inside the nullptr check is not reachable (see screenshot 
https://paste.pics/KUHRC). The highlighted bodies lines are the lint warnings.

Comment: A screenshot with the warning: https://paste.pics/KUHT8

Comment: Unreachable makes sense, because it "dies" with the end of the `try block scope`. My initial hypothesis was that this is some weird warning based on the fact that `malloc(...)` would return `null_ptr` if it couldn't allocate the memory and `new` would throw `std::bad_alloc`. The uncaught exception would kill the program, but the `null_ptr` would end with a `segfault` during runtime, hence the warning.  But this isn't the case.

Comment: There is one more idea that I have, could you change `(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)` to `(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)`, while keeping the rest of the code the same?

Comment: @MilanŠ. Still appears.

Comment: Looks like a false positive. Try running with `-fsanitize=address` to make sure the code works.

Comment: @Dawid I think I'm gonna side with the false positive here. I just don't see any reason why it would ever buffer overflow.

Comment: @Dawid That’s still too big, try `Body<short int, int[3], int[3]>`, or with `char` s